# Postman doesn't get correct type of Int variable in a GraphQL call

Tags: graphql, postman

I've set the body of request like this:

[image]

The call return me this error message:

> "Variable "$idCentralina" got invalid value "1"; Expected type Int. Int cannot represent non-integer value: "1""

I don't understand why it get `idCentralina` like a string if in the declaration when I use an Integer (without quote) to initialize it.

In gql schema the query is this:

```
getCoseByCentralina(
      idCentralina: Int
      date: String
    ): [Cose]
```

Does someone know the cause? and explain to me why this happens.

**UPDATE**

If I insert the Int value in the query without using the variables it works.

[image]

Hopefully somebody knows the cause of the problem of postman variables.

**EDIT - SOLUTION OF MY CASE**

I find the problem, a custom middleware of backend converts all `req.body` params into String type, I don't know why.

Comment: `query SomeMissingQueryName ($idCentralina.... { getCose...` ??

Comment: Thanks for answer but I try to put the query name but the call return the same error. I tried to declare `idCentralina` like String type everywhere and pass a string, this works, return me the correct data but I want pass an integer not a string

Comment: it depends on server type defs

Comment: you can answer your own question